# Do short-circuiting terminal operations in java streams behave differently on different VMs?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List` of some objects and create a parallel stream on it, I run some operations that end up with `allMatch()` like below:

```
if(objects.parallelStream().[...].allMatch(this::hasException)) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

I see different behavior of this pipeline on different `VMs` (local machine and `Bamboo`).

On my local machine all the elements are processed.

It never happened that one was missed. On `Bamboo` just some. Most of the time the first two. It never happened that all were processed.

As `allMatch()` is a short-circuiting terminal operation, I can understand that not all elements are processed, but I would always expect the same behavior everywhere.

I did not find any documentation / explanation about this.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: how do you know that "some" are missed? but either way, if `allMatch` would report `false`, "some" missed is more than OK and your local and Bamboo machine might have different number of CPU's and the spliterator might split these in a different way - thus the observed behavior, but I am mainly guessing.

Comment: I know that not all of them are processed because I've put some logs to analyse the problem. One more argument is that I can see the result of the pipeline operations inside the objects in the list.I have to mention that the person writing the code did not know that `allMatch()` is short-circuiting (I also found out while analyzing the problem)

Comment: That `allMatch()` skips a part of the elements is OK, it is supposed to do that. I have no problem with that. The thing I could not understand is the different behavior. Splitting the list because of the number of CPUs could be the explanation.

Comment: even if it is, why do you care as long as you have the correct result...

Comment: What I did not say (because it is not relevant to the question) is that the code was relying on all elements being processed. So I did not have the correct / expected result of the pipeline. The question was about the different behavior on different machines.

Comment: that is the problem, relying on side-effects, which documentation warns about in various places. If you could explain the problem you have, there might be better options for you